# In a WPF key handler, can I programmatically change/override the key that was pressed?

Tags: wpf, event-handling, keyboard-events

As it states in the title, we're trying to intercept one key and replace it with another.  Think similar to key remapping.

Our specific usage is to change the left and right arrow keys to behave like Shift-Tab and Tab respectively.

Now I know I can intercept those and manually control the focus, but I'm trying to leverage as much of the built-in navigation behavior as possible.  We just want to (also) use the arrow keys for that type of behavior.

Only thing I can think of is to swallow the event, then re-throw it with the correct parameters but I'm concerned that will interfere with things like key release, repeating, etc.

I'm also open to other ways of doing this if this isn't actually possible.  Again, our goal is to leverage the built-in behaviors, just via other keys.

Comment: Don't know if you can change the event to indicate a different key; but you should be able to mark the event as Handled, then raise a new one with the re-mapped key.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said above, but I'm concerned that by marking it as 'Handled' I may lose other things like releases, repeats, etc.  Guess it's time for a test app!

Comment: Rather than trying to remap the keys, why not bind the keys to whatever commands are bound to your the `Tab` and `Shift-Tab` combinations?

Comment: There are no commands (that I'm aware of) for those keys.  Again, this is system-defined behavior. (Note that there are common ComponentCommands but they are specifically for move left, right, etc., not tabbing.)

Comment: I am with Jeff.  If you don't have a specific application action for those keys then why do you need to remap them?  You can always react to the key then fire the base.

Comment: @MarqueIV: The `ComponentCommands.MoveFocusForward` and `ComponentCommands.MoveFocusBack` commands would be very appropriate here. I don't know why you wouldn't think so unless you just overlooked them. It's just a matter of binding to them and implementing the actual focus change which is rather simple.

Comment: I didn't see them in the list of commands that I found.  That's exactly what I'm looking for for this specific case.  Still, I'd be interested to know if it is possible to override keys (however, I think that goes to true subclassing or rather windows hooks and not something you can do at the app level.) I'll mark yours as the answer though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your goal is to map the arrow keys to do some keyboard tab navigation, you should map the appropriate commands to the keys and implement them.  The `ComponentCommands.MoveFocusForward` and `ComponentCommands.MoveFocusBack` commands would be appropriate here as that's what we're doing, moving focus forward to the next or back to the previous control.

Here's an example how you could do all that.

First you'll need to bind the commands to your keys.

```xaml
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ComponentCommands.MoveFocusForward" Executed="MoveFocusForward_Executed" />
    <CommandBinding Command="ComponentCommands.MoveFocusBack" Executed="MoveFocusBack_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="ComponentCommands.MoveFocusForward" Key="Right" />
    <KeyBinding Command="ComponentCommands.MoveFocusBack" Key="Left" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Then implement the handlers.

```
private static bool RequestFocusChange(FocusNavigationDirection direction)
{
    var focused = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
    if (focused != null)
    {
        return focused.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(direction));
    }
    return false;
}

private void MoveFocusForward_Executed(object target, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RequestFocusChange(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
}

private void MoveFocusBack_Executed(object target, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RequestFocusChange(FocusNavigationDirection.Previous);
}
```

Comment: Question for you... I was wondering why you even added the handlers and the command binding in the first place.  Wouldn't simply setting the InoutBinding do the trick? (In our code, it's actually something else that's going on so I'm building a test app with your code to find out, but if those are standard commands, shouldn't the standard controls respond to them intrinsically?

Comment: As far as I know, the predefined commands are just a means of providing a standard set of commands to bind to. There is no implementation associated with them. e.g., You can allow an "Open" command to do something that makes sense to your application and not necessarily bring up a FileOpenDialog (or other predefined behavior).  I know you're looking for that predefined behavior but I'm afraid it just isn't available.

Comment: I would of course agree with something like 'Open', but these commands you're mentioning are pre-defined behaviors that already exist.  In other words, 'Open' has no context except in an application-specific way, but moving focus to the next control isn't an application-specific thing, but rather an OS-level one, so I'm not sure that statement is actually correct because again, that behavior *is* already implemented.  It's just how does it get called.  There has to be a way to tap into the built-in behavirs without you having to re-write their implementation as you have done here.